# reporting services - datedif between grouped column 'time'

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, reporting-services

I have a Tablix with a group. For each group, I want the date difference of the column: 
**Time (timestamp)** from the prior group.

Pseudo code:

```
=DateDiff(PriorGroup!Fields!Time,ThisGroup!Fields!Time)
```

Answer (score 2):

Datepart is missing afaik, check this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms189794.aspx